# "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected \",\" (20:2)", ')' expected(1005)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, token, blockchain, solidity

I am trying to deploy my Token onto the blockchain I am getting a simple error code but I cant seem to figure it out as I am new to Visual Studio Code and cant seem to figure it out. Looking if i can get some help on what could be the reason i see this so often. Can easily be a rookie mistake but i am trying to learn so i can limit my mistakes

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main()  {
// Fetch contract to deploy
const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")

// Deploy contract
const token = await Token.deploy()
await token.deployed()
console.log{"Token Deployed to: ${token.address"}};

;


// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1();


})


const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const hre = require("hardhat")

async function main() {
// Fetch contract to deploy
const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")

// Deploy contract
const token = await Token.deploy
await token. deployed()
console.log('Token Deployed to: ${token.address}')

}

/ We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors. 1 is not a function, you have extra semis, incorrectly formatted comments, and are using template strings incorrectly. You also had the entire contents in there twice, which may have been a copy-paste issue. See my comments in the below code for the fixes.

```js
// moved this require to the top, though it's never used so could be deleted
const hre = require("hardhat")
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main()  {
  // Fetch contract to deploy
  const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")

  // Deploy contract
  const token = await Token.deploy()
  await token.deployed()
  console.log(`Token Deployed to: ${token.address}`);    // this line -- template strings need backticks, not quotes
  // add missing closing brace here
}

// you have the whole contents of your code in here twice;
// i deleted the second copy, but in that copy, the following comment began with
// one slash, not two
// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1)                                     // this line -- read the docs for process.exit
})
```